# Redirect from Woocommerce to Php core with the Order ID in the URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, redirect, hook-woocommerce

I am working on two websites ( WordPress/Woocommerce and PHP core). I don't know what I want to do is possible or not but I need your suggestions.

I want to redirect customer after a purchase from Woocommerce to PHP core website including the Order ID in the URL.

Is this possible or there is any other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: you can use `woocommerce_thankyou` hook to redirect to your php file

Comment: can i redirect with any database value in URL?

Comment: yes you can redirect with DB value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Wordpress dedicated `template_redirect` hook to make a redirection after a purchase and pass any order data through the url like in this example:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'order_received_redirection' );
function order_received_redirection() {
    // Only on "Order received" page
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        global $wp;
        $order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $key = isset( $_GET['key'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['key'] ) : $order->get_order_key();
        $total = $order->get_total();

        // HERE BELOW Set your redirection url
        $url_redirect = 'http://www.my-domain.com/?orderid='.$order_id . '&key=' . $key . '&total=' . $total;

        // Redirect 
        wp_redirect( $url_redirect );
        exit(); // Always exit
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: Thanks, Man. You made my day.

Comment: how to access order details from the PHP core website?

Comment: @Ajay Is better to send all needed data through the URL to PHP core … To access Orders data from PHP core you will need to use the Woocommerce REST API.